# API request fails on Travis-CI

Tags: testing, heroku, travis-ci, enzyme

I have a React App with multiple passing tests. When running them through Travis, I get the following error:

`API request failed.
Message: The requested API endpoint was not found. Are you using the right HTTP verb (i.e.`GET`vs.`POST`), and did you specify your intended version with the`Accept`header?`

I use the .env to set a variable to the heroku URL. Then i set the same variable in the Travis .env on their website. I suspect that the API fails for the action tests, but I can't seem to fix it.

Anyone had a similar experience and knows where to fix the issues? Will provide any additional code examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by doing this:

```
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: ENCRYPTED-PW
  app: boiling-spring-21825  <------------
  on:
    repo: xyz/project-name
```

Before, I had the `app` name as `https://boiling-spring-21825:21825`, hence Travis was unable to fetch the project from heroku. I can imagine the API was looking for `https://boiling-spring-21825:21825/https://boiling-spring-21825:21825` or something similar that didn't make sense.

Lesson here is to only write out the simple heroku app name as found in your heroku projects page.